# XCreateWindow - parent argument implications

Tags: x11, xlib

When I create a main window of my X11 application I specify a root window as a `XCreateWindow` parent argument. My application allow to open a dialog boxes, for example "Open File" window. When I create such window I pass a main window as a `XCreateWindow` parent argument. It looks logical but what are implications of that choice ? I could also pass a root window as a dialog box parent window. Is it somehow related to a `override-redirect flag` or calling `XSetTransientForHint`?

Comment: "When I create such window I pass a main window as a XCreateWindow parent argument" Are you sure? Such windows normally won't be dialog boxes etc. Only children of the root window are managed by the WM.

Comment: You're right, I pass a root window as a dialog box parent. You have also answered my question - "Only children of the root window are managed by the WM".